# Spread Liquid `include` over mutliple lines

Tags: yaml, jekyll, liquid

I have an "included" template with several parameters. The contents of the parameters get a bit muddled if I cram them all into a single line, so I would prefer something like this:

```
{% include product_details 
    weight= "5.8lbs (2.6 kg)"
    width=  "22&quot; (56cm)"
    length= "49&quot; (125cm)"
    thickness= "1¼&quot; (3cm)"
    case= "MT51413" 
%}
```

However, this gives me the following error when generating the site:

> error: Tag '{%' was not properly terminated with regexp: /\%}/.

Is there any way to spread a Liquid `include` over several lines?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry you can't, the liquid parser expects the whole statement in one line, this is true for all statements not only for `include`, try to split an `if` statement and you receive the same error